# CODEIGNITER - FPDF Displaying Footer

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

Good Day! I would like to ask how to put a footer in pdf using FPDF in codeigniter. Where to put this block of code?

```
     function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
```

Is it in the library or in controller?